# selenium in python: click() doesn't work within method

Tags: python, selenium, methods, click

I'm considering a method which performs scrolling down for 138px continuously until an attribute shows up and gets clicked.

It works fine accordingly without method:

```
div_height = 138
total_height = div_height
while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='item']").click()
        break
    except:
        driver.execute_script(
        "document.querySelector('div.result').scrollTo(0, " + str(total_height) + ");"
            )
        total_height += div_height
```

But if I try to send the driver over a method, it doesn't work. Take a look:

```
def scroll_down_until_done(action, selectors):
    div_height = 138
    total_height = div_height
    while True:
        try:
            action
            break
        except:
            driver.execute_script(
                "document.querySelector(\'" + str(selectors) + "\').scrollTo(0, " + str(total_height) + ");"
            )
            total_height += div_height

scroll_down_until_done(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='item']").click(), "div.result")
```

Then shows error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/electronyoon/Documents/GitHub/crawler/com/cralwer.py", line 203, in <module>
    parser()
  File "/Users/electronyoon/Documents/GitHub/crawler/com/cralwer.py", line 197, in parser
    active_and_expired_manager()
  File "/Users/electronyoon/Documents/GitHub/crawler/com/cralwer.py", line 142, in active_and_expired_manager
    scroll_down_until_done(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='apt-item']")[4].click(), "div.result")
  File "/Users/electronyoon/Documents/GitHub/crawler/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Users/electronyoon/Documents/GitHub/crawler/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Users/electronyoon/Documents/GitHub/crawler/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/electronyoon/Documents/GitHub/crawler/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)
```

I hardly understand the difference. Any help?

Comment: These snippets are not equivalent. `click()` returns `None`.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Is there any way to perform click command within method? I tried getattr(driver, "...click()") but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two code snippets are not the same. `scroll_down_until_done()` actually triggers `driver.find_element_by_xpath()` and afterwards `click()` before even entering `scroll_down_until_done`. You need to send the name of the function and invoke it by using `action()`

```
def scroll_down_until_done(action, selector_to_click, selectors):
    div_height = 138
    total_height = div_height
    while True:
        try:
            action(selector_to_click).click()
            break
        except:
            driver.execute_script(
                "document.querySelector(\'" + str(selectors) + "\').scrollTo(0, " + str(total_height) + ");"
            )
            total_height += div_height

scroll_down_until_done(driver.find_element_by_xpath, "//div[@class='item']", "div.result")
```

Answer (score 0):

Newb. With the help of comment above, I remade.
I send an web element instead and make it clicked.

```
def scroll_down_until_done(element, selectors):
    div_height = 138
    total_height = div_height
    while True:
        try:
            element.click()
            break
        except:
            driver.execute_script(
                "document.querySelector(\'" + str(selectors) + "\').scrollTo(0, " + str(total_height) + ");"
            )
            total_height += div_height

element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='item']")
scroll_down_until_done(element, "div.result")
```

hope this would help for other people.